# Why .Xauthority needs not to be owned by the root account in order to get past login?

Tags: xorg, login, x-server

I've just got the same problem from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189399/cannot-get-past-login-screen), and solved it using what was stated in the first answer (akonsu's one).

However, I would love to know why `~/.Xauthority` needs not to be owned by the root account in order to get past login with a regular user (in other words: why is that the reason for the login failure), and - do you have an assumption as to how akonsu found that as a solution?

Answer (score 5):

> However, I would love to know why ~/.Xauthority needs not to be owned by the root account in order to get past login with a regular user (in other words: why is that the reason for the login failure)

Because X wants to write/replace that file when it starts your session.  If you do not have write permissions on it, then it can't do that.

> do you have an assumption as to how akonsu found that as a solution?

Perhaps by looking at `/var/log/Xorg.[N].log`, where `N` is (I think) the display number, probably 0.  It is helpful if you are having problems getting X to start.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a guess why the permissions changed? This is a clean install, and at some point I ran the `startx` command.

Comment: Can someone make an assumption?

Answer (score 4):

.Xauthority is actually a security feature of X, the graphical system. It part of what prevents unauthorized access to your graphical session(s), key loggers or tracking mouse clicks for example.

Security is a broad topic, and .Xauthority is one part of security mind you and covers local access, not necessarily tracking of mouse clicks by web sites ;)

> Xauth allows access to anyone who knows the right secret. Such a secret is called an authorization record, or a magic cookie. This authorization scheme is formally called MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1.
>
> The cookies for different displays are stored together in ~/.Xauthority. **Your ~/.Xauthority must be inaccessible for group/other users.** The xauth program manages these cookies, hence the nickname xauth for the scheme.

For additional information, see:

http://linuxtutorial.info/modules.php?name=Howto&pagename=Remote-X-Apps/Remote-X-Apps-6.html

and

http://www.biac.duke.edu/library/documentation/xwin32/security.html